# How to make two floating div elements on the same line?

Tags: html

I am trying to make two elements on the same line, with one floating left and the other floating right. The first one is just basic text and the second is a search box (it has a css to go with it, but I won't include that here). They are both aligned properly but the search box is one line beneath the text. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
     <div id="outer" style="width:100%">  
     <div id="inner">
     <div class="toolbar-wrapper wrapper">
     <div class="toolbar span12 clearfix">
     <ul class="unstyled">
      <div id=123A style="float: left; text-align: left;">MADE WITH ♡ IN CANADA ― EST. 2014</div>
      <div id=123B style="float: right; text-align: right;">
      <li class="search-field fl">
        <form class="search" action="/search">
          <input type="image" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0041/t/1/assets/icon-search.png?56" alt="Go" id="go">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="search_box" placeholder="Search" value="{{ search.terms }}"  />
        </form>
      </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it is showing right where you want. Probably your text on the left is too long. You can give both `width: 50%` so that will fix the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz76u30f/1/)